# Using jQuery to get unknown data attributes and copy them to new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a custom dropdown select style by converting a standard form select into a `<li>` list, however I need to add a few `-data` attributes to each `<option>` which then need to be copied over to the `<li>`.

The problem is that I do not always know what those data attributes will be called and therefore I would like a way of just copying any data attributes from the `<option>` tag onto the `<li>` tag.

My current code is as follows:

Original `<option>` tag...

```
<option data-somedata="something" data-else="something else" value="some value">Hello</option>
```

And the jQuery...

```
jQuery('.fancy-select .field option').each(function(){
  jQuery(this).parents('.fancy-select').find('ul').append('<li><a href="">' + jQuery(this).text() + '</a></li>')
});
```

Is there a way of copying all data attributes from my option tag to the `<li>` tags without specifying them by name?

Comment: Does requirement include all `attributes` of `option`, or only `data-` ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 - I suppose for now I'm only interested in getting the `data-` attributes

Comment: If possible, can post all `html` block ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [clone the node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode):

```
jQuery('.fancy-select .field option').each(function(){
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode());
});
```

Since this is [vanilla](http://vanilla-js.com), and DOM manipulation instead of string manipulation, it will be much faster. And it's nice and simple too.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5DCH/)

But you want it to be an `<li>`, not an `<option>`? You could change the outerHTML, but a faster way is:

```
jQuery('.fancy-select .field option').each(function() {
    var newNode = document.createElement('li');
    for (var i = this.attributes.length - 1; i--;) {
        newNode.attributes.setNamedItem(this.attributes[i].cloneNode());
    }
    this.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(newNode);
});
```

Instead of cloning the entire node, then doing an expensive outerHTML replacement, it just copies attributes one by one!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sR4f3/)

Comment: Where does it say "only data attributes"? And parentNode is fine for this specific case. Options are in selects, there are no other elements besides the option and select.

Comment: bjb568 - bear with me - I'm just looking into the parentNode stuff. It's not something I'm familier with, so I'm going to need to look into it before attempting to get it working. +1 for now though (unsure why you were downvoted in the first place!). Will accept once/if I get it working if that's ok? :)

Comment: Ok, that's what the accept button is for (marking it as working, after you test it). I think the downvote was just *cough* some user being jealous that my solution, you know, works.

Comment: Assuming it's not just the "data-" attributes - which I can't spot the requirement for after re-reading the question - +1

Comment: @Jake It appears to be pretty much what OP wants. I mean there's an element, then OP creates a new one. Duplication is the efficient way.

Comment: Apologies bjb568, I'm having a little trouble trying to get my head around this. Using cloneNode basically clones the element as I understand it. I can't seem to work out how to copy the attributes from the `<option>` elements to the newly created `<li>` elements - could you provide a little assistance in to how this would actually work with my code? Much appreciated

Comment: Oh, typo. I fixed it now. And added a fiddle.

Comment: I still don't understand - you have duplicated an `<option>` element, but my original question is how I can copy any data attributes from the `<option>` element onto the `<li>` elements that are created in my original code. Am I missing something? Apologies if I'm being a bit dense (it's late here in the UK!)

Comment: You can change the tag name with outerHTML after cloning.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I've used jQuery, but my first thought would be to look through the attributes looking for the "data-" ones.

Something like:

```
jQuery('.fancy-select .field option').each(function(){
    var $li = jQuery( '<li><a href="">' + jQuery(this).text() + '</a></li>' );
    jQuery.each( this.attributes, function ( item ) {
        if ( item.name.substring(0,6) === "data-" ) {
            $li.attr( item.name, item.value );
        }
    } );

    jQuery(this).parents('.fancy-select').find('ul').append( $li );
});
```

A quick Google reveals that data() might make this code much simplier if you are using a newer version of jQuery - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

```
jQuery('.fancy-select .field option').each(function(){
    var $li = jQuery( '<li><a href="">' + jQuery(this).text() + '</a></li>' );
    jQuery.each( jQuery(this).data(), function ( key, value ) {
        $li.data( key, value );
    } );

    jQuery(this).parents('.fancy-select').find('ul').append( $li );
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, this looks like what I was after. I've accepted another solution, but +1 from me for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (pattern)

html (e.g.)

```
<ul class="selections">
    <select>
        <option data-somedata="something" data-else="something else" value="some value">abc</option>
        <option data-somedata="something other" data-else="something else other" value="some value">def</option>
    </select>
</ul>
```

js

```
function optdata(selector, container, el) {
    $.each($(selector), function (index, value) {
        $(container).append(
        $(el).html("<a href=''>" + $(value).html() + "</a>")
        .data($(value).data()) 
        );
        return (index != $(value).size())
    });
};
optdata($("option"), $(".selections"), "<li>");
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/9NvJm/

Comment: Thanks guest271314 - this works. I've accepted bjb568's answer though, as his works also and I can only accept one answer. +1 from me though :)

Comment: I've just seen that your jsfiddle doesn't actually copy across the data attributes onto the `<li>`'s..

Comment: See console at jsfiddle, `.data()` from `option:first` should be duplicated at `li:first` ? Thanks

Comment: But I can't see any data attribute on the `<li>` - is this normal? So the data is there, I just can't see it?

Comment: @wickywills From what able to interpret, `jQuery.data()`, or `.data()`, appear different than actual composed html5 `data-*`, `dataset` accessed at `DOM` `element`, i.e.g., `$("option")[0].dataset.somedata`. instead of jQuery `.data()` or `$.data()` `object`. Some browser extensions, may display `jquery` `data`, including `events`, etc, not `displayed` in `html` `document`. Perhaps, similar to `$("body").append("<li></li>")`, if save `document` `.append()` ed jquery `object` $`("li")`, not normally present , see api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ , ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/